# useState, UseRef, or useMemo, what should I prefer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

I have a scenario where I need to store the output of a function throughout the component life cycle(this value should never change).

consider the example below

```
const UniqueIdView = () => {
    const [uniqueIdState1] = useState(() => uniqueId('prefix_'))
    const [uniqueIdState2] = useState(uniqueId('prefix_'))
    const uniqueIdRef = useRef(uniqueId('prefix_'))
    const uniqueIdMemo = useMemo(() => uniqueId('prefix_'), [])
    return (
        <div>
            {uniqueIdState1}
            {uniqueIdState2}
            {uniqueIdRef.current}
            {uniqueIdMemo}
       </div>
    )
}
```

which out of the 4 approaches mentioned above is ideal?

My understanding:

`useState` should be used to store values where the change in value should trigger re-render.

`useMemo` should be used in case I want to memoize the calculation, and memoization always has an associated cost.

So, `useRef` in my opinion is suitable.

But, I then have one confusion:

`useRef` will trigger my function again and again on every re-render while using the callback approach with `useState` will trigger my function only once.

But again, If I have to think of the cost of calling the function again and again, should I use `useMemo` (but in this case, the function is not complex, should we add the memorization overhead)?

**Update**

What do I want to achieve?

I want to create a custom hook that should return `uniqueId` which should not change on re-render

```
const UniqueId = () {
    const uniqueId = useStableUniqueId('prefix__')
    return <div>{uniqueId}<div>
}
```

so no matter how many time UniqueId re-renders the value should not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value passed to `useRef` is only the initial value, but if it's a function invokation it will actually be called each render. Not so sure about the rest of your question. Each hook exists for a specific purpose. Pick the one that serves your needs.

> I have a scenario where I need to store the output of a function
> throughout the component life cycle.

To me the clear choice is the `useMemo` hook to memoize the result value of a *possibly* expensive function call.

It's *not* regularly updated so `useState` doesn't fit. If you decided to store it in state and ever needed to updated it, you would need an `useEffect` hook with dependency and recompute a new value and call the state updater function. This is essentially the `useMemo` hook.

If you decided to store it in a React ref then you'd again need to pair that with a `useEffect` with a dependency to update the `ref.current` value to keep it updated, and this, again, essentially gets you the `useMemo` hook.

## Update

Since you are really looking to optimize a custom hook that provides a static unique id for the life of the component:

1. Using `useMemo`

   ```
   const useUniqueId = (prefix = 'prefix_') => {
     return useMemo(() => uniqueId(prefix), []);
   };
   ```
2. Using `useState`

   ```
   const useUniqueId = (prefix = 'prefix_') => {
     const [uniqueId] = useState(() => uniqueId(prefix));
     return uniqueId;
   };
   ```

Comment: Great answer -as always- but I have a BUT...`The value passed to useRef is only the initial value, so if it's a function invokation it'll only be invoked once.` Your answer is not correct regarding this sentence. If I pass a function to `useRef` than the function is never invoked and just stored as a reference to a function. If I pass the result of a function call to `useRef` that function is invoked on every render. The OP was right in his assessment concerning this fact. Will writup my answer shortly.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your response but `useRef(uniqueId('prefix_'))` will trigger `uniqueId` on every re-render. I have created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-playground-forked-pl77f?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Martin Ah, dang, you're absolutely correct. I'll amend my statement.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I checked the code, and I checked the documentation just now just to be sure, with `useRef(uniqueId('prefix_'))` each time the component rerenders the function (in fact both functions: `useRef()` and `uniqueId()`) is invoked again. Only that useRef will discard any initialization value after the first invokation. But invoked they are.

Comment: @Martin Yes, you provide me doubt... I also quickly stood up a codesandbox and discovered I was wrong about that. Learn something new every day.  Thanks mate.

Comment: @DrewReese `useMemo` is perfect for a complex function, where I don't want to compute again, but what about the case where my function is not complex and I am only generating a unique string? Should I go with `useRef` over `useState`?

Comment: @Ashish `useMemo` is perfect for any value you want to memoize. If it's function then there's benefit to memoizing the result, no matter how simple the computation is. Is this value something that needs to be computed within a component? In other words, is it something that can be generated in the enclosing file scope of the component? Can you provide a more accurate version of your use-case?

Comment: @DrewReese think of my issue like this => I need to create a hook `useUniqueId` this hook should return a fixed string on every re-render. this means component should mount with a fixed uniqueId, and this value should not change throughout the life cycle.

Comment: @Ashish In this case it almost doesn't matter, `const [uniqueId] = useState(uniqueId('prefix_')); return uniqueId;` is about the same as `return useMemo(() => uniqueId('prefix_'), []);` for a custom hook implementation. I'd argue the `useMemo` is a bit more succinct, but outside this they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @DrewReese Understood thanks, one more question with a similar case, consider I need to store the time when the `ComponentX` mounted. so then also, `useMemo` is better? 
`const mountTime = useMemo(() => new Date(), [])` or, this makes sense `const mountTime = useRef(new Date())` ? From what I understood from your answer I should use `useMemo` only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232989/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ashish).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer first: If I had to decide which mechanism to use I would go for `useMemo`:

```
const uniqueId = useMemo(() => getUniqueId('prefix_'), []);
```

It does all the things we want here: the `getId` function is only ever called once because the dependency array is empty, the returned value is stable, it is cost efficient. There is no magic cost associated with `useMemo` and it does not matter whether the calculation is heavy or lightweight. And as Drew said its succinct.
A custom hook would look like this:

```
export const useUniqueId = () => {
  const uniqueId = useMemo(() => getUniqueId('prefix_'), []);
  return uniqueId;
}
```

The longer answer:
Usually if you want a value that is not in any way connected to the render cycle and that will be stable during the lifetime of the component I would go for `useRef`.
But `useRef` does not support an initializer function as does `useState` or `useMemo`. I would not like to invoke `getUniqueID` on every render and therefore would be forced to combine it with a `useEffect` to initialize the ref. And that's really a bit cumbersome here, so I think `useMemo` does the job here.

```
const uniqueId = useRef();
useEffect(() => { uniqueId.current = getUniqueId('prefix_') }, []);
```

And notice that the solution with useEffect will only provide the value after the render function has run to its completion, which will cause trouble if you need the uniqueID immediatly e.g. to set the HTML attribute ID on some element.